# Making a list-function acting one-to one in a list of elements

Tags: functions, function-construction, functional-style

Consider a pair of functions `f1` and `f2`, and a vector `{x,y}`. I can get easily `{f1[x],f2[y]}` by doing `MapThread[#1@#2 &,{f1,f2},{x,y}]`.

Now imagine that I have a function `F` defined as

```
F := {f1[#],f2[#]} &
```

Of course I cannot use the same procedure to get the same result, because now `F` is not a list of functions (as it was `{f1,f2}`), but a function itself that returns a list.

One way to get this result (and that admits generalization to longer lists) is

```
Diagonal[F/@{x,y}]
```

With this solution we build a whole matrix of elements of `F` acting on elements of the arguments list and we select the ones that we want.

I was wondering if there is a solution kind of like `MapThread` that gives the direct result, making act one-to-one the $n$-th element of the function with the $n$-th argument.

Comment: Using `:=` for `F` is strange here.  Are you aware of the distinction between Set and SetDelayed?

Comment: I am. `f1` and `f2` are supposed to stand for concrete functions in this case (for example, `F := {D[#,x],D[#,y]}&`).

Comment: `:=` is never needed if the right-hand side only has a `Function` (i.e. `...&`).  That's because `Function` already holds its arguments.  It doesn't hurt to use `:=` but the result will be exactly the same as it would have been with `=`.

Comment: Thanks, I had never thought about it. Is any of them recommended?

Comment: I use `=` for OwnValue assignments unless there is a special reason not to. If I see `:=`, I automatically look for a special reason. This is of course just my way of working. I can't think of a technical reason why `:=` is bad here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `f = {f1[#], f2[#], f3[#]} &;` you can also turn `f` into a list of functions using

```
Function/@f[[1]]
```

or using

```
First@MapAt[Function, f, {1, All}] (* thanks : Szabolcs *)
Thread[f] (* thanks: WReach *)
```

and then  `MapThread` the resulting function list with the argument list:

```
ClearAll[mthreadF]
mthreadF = MapThread[#@#2 &, {Thread@#, #2}] &;

mthreadF[f, {x, y, z}]
```

> {f1[x], f2[y], f3[z]}

Alternatively, you can use `Inner`:

```
ClearAll[innerF]
innerF = Inner[#@#2 &, Thread@#, #2, List] &;

innerF[f, {x, y, z}]
```

> {f1[x], f2[y], f3[z]}

Comment: The difficulty is evaluation control. The OP said that he actually has things such as `{D[#,x],D[#,y]}&`.  Dealing with this, plus dealing with the various allowed syntaxes for `Function` makes this complicated. That is why I said that "There isn't a *reasonable* way ...".  But looking at your post maybe it isn't quite as unreasonable ... How about `First@MapAt[Function, f, {1, All}]` for simple slot-based functions like what you considered?

Comment: @Szabolcs, thank you. `First@MapAt[Function, f, {1, All}]` is clever. I will update with your suggestion.

Comment: I think that this is the answer I was looking for. The key resides in transforming the function `f` that returns a list of functions in the list of functions, solved with the `MapAt`. I found it quite elegant.

Comment: If we are allowed to assume that _f_ is precisely of the form `{...}&`, then `Thread[f]` will perform the required conversion and thus `mthreadF = MapThread[#@#2 &, {Thread[#], #2}] &;`.

Comment: @WReach,  thank you ! I added your suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a reasonable way to avoid *computing* both `f1` and `f2` in this case.  But we can avoid *storing* the whole matrix, which would (temporarily) take up a lot of memory.  One way is [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html).

```
f = {f1[#], f2[#]} &;

MapIndexed[Extract[f[#1], #2] &, {x, y}]
(* {f1[x], f2[y]} *)
```

Unless the lists are large enough that the matrix would take up a lot of memory, it's probably not worth bothering with this. I would choose your solution with `Diagonal` because I find it clearer than `MapIndexed`.  This is, of course, just my personal preference.